# 18.04 upgrade only boots to command-line screen

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I've been running 17.10, which is completely updated and current, and trying to upgrade to 18.04.  My system should be perfectly capable of the new distribution, it's a quad-core AMD system running nVidia GTX 550 graphics.  (I also run Windows 10 on it, with all the latest upgrades, and a copy of Win 7 just for old times' sake.)

I've tried it multiple times using command-line (both with and without the Developer option) and using the GUI method, and every time, the upgrade seems to complete flawlessly, but in the end, it reboots to a black screen with command-line only. It wants a login and password (which I've never used before, always login automatically), then tells me "Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS", and some further tidbits of info, then returns to a command prompt, still on an otherwise black screen.

Obviously, this is a problem, so I've wiped it and restored to the previous build (again).  Anybody have any ideas as to what's going wrong?
The full text of how my screen appears after upgrading follows:

---

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS BigBoy tty1 [NOTE:  BigBoy is my computer's name, no laughing]

BigBoy login:dave

Password:

Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:  https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:  https:ubuntu.com/advantage

* Meltdown, Spectre and Ubuntu:  What are the attack vectors, how the fixes work, 
and everything else you need to know -- https:ubu.one/u2know

0 packages can be updated
0 updates are security updates

You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that are going 
out of support on 2016-08-04.

There is a graphics stack installed on this system.  An upgrade to a configuration 
supported for the full lifetime of the LTS will become available on 2016-07-21 and 
can be installed by running "update manager" in the Dash.

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;  the exact 
distribution terms for each program are described in the individual files in 
/usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by applicable law.

dave@BigBoy:"$
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and this fixed it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029509/no-gui-after-kubuntu-18-04-lts-upgrade-from-17-10

Comment: That sounds promising, considering the nature of the messages that came up in the above login text.  (Although why anything "becoming available on 2016-07-21", as if it's a future date, is showing up in a 2018 upgrade is beyond me.)  I'll give that a shot in a few days, when I have time to re-run the upgrade, login, kick-start the GUI, and then run that command in a terminal.

Comment: That took care of it.

Answer (score 5):

"startx" will indeed get you into the normal desktop environment from command-line purgatory.  Once in, from the link Helene gave me, the problem was easy to fix.  Apparently the upgrade process leaves display manager package "lightdm" in a broken state, and it has to be reinstalled (then selected in place of "gdm").  So it was just a matter of running "sudo apt-get install lightdm", once the system was up.  Now everything boots normally.

Answer (score 1):

type startx in the terminal.

this should bring up the new environment.

Or it might give you lots of errors, that you can add to your question!

Comment: As I said, I've already wiped it by restoring to a still-functional 17.10.  What I want to know is what I can do differently to create an upgrade that DOESN'T go straight to a command-line terminal, not how to work around it.  I want an upgrade that boots into Ubuntu's GUI.

Comment: I imagine the Ubuntu experts are up to their necks in it at the moment, so you are not going to get a proper answer.