# No GUI after Kubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 17.10, lightdm, 18.04

I have an MSI GP72 Laptop. I upgraded from 17.10 → 18.04 LTS a few hours ago today. The upgrade process itself went well. (Unlike [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1027240/535457), I'm using the final official release.)

However, while I can boot the system, I can only get a terminal. The GUI is nowhere to be seen.

What I need is help in:

- finding what/where the error is, and
- fixing it so that I can get the GUI back

Any and all help is appreciated.

---

I've been unable to find explicit error reports. Here're a few of the places I've already checked:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/kern.log`
- `/var/log/boot.log`

The `boot.log` entries show `[OK]`s for the services, including `[OK] Started Login Service.`. Interestingly, the `lightdm` entry shows up as follows

```
...
[OK] Started LSB: GNOME Display Manager.
[OK] Started Permit User Sessions.
[OK] Started Disk Manager.
     Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
     Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
     Starting Light Display Manager...
...
[OK] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
...
```

Checking the status of `lightdm.service` shows the following (I've omitted date stamps with `<date>` to avoid clutter):

```
$ systemctl status lightdm.service
lightdm.service - LSB: Start lightdm
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/lightdm; generated)
  Active: active (exited) since <date>; 1h 2min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 3251 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/lightdm stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 3327 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/lightdm start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

<date> msi-hive systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start lightdm...
<date> msi-hive systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start lightdm.
```

So, for whatever reason the service seems to exit after getting launched and its exit code is "successful".

The `systemctl start lightdm.service` command simply returns to the terminal and shows nothing (i.e. no output, errors, etc). Changing to other terminals using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1-F8</kbd> keys doesn't show a working GUI elsewhere either.

---

Please note the meta announcement stating that [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17863/535457).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***TL;DR;*** Run `sudo apt-get install lightdm` to let the system discover and install missing dependencies. In this case, the upgrade appears to have removed `bindfs`, so it had to be re-installed.

---

It turns out that the `lightdm` package was left in a broken state after upgrading. The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` command ended up exiting with an error and saying that the `lightdm` package was `broken or not completely installed`.

So, running `sudo apt-get install lightdm` again *after* the upgrade had completed showed that `bindfs` was not installed. While, according to `apt-cache show lightdm`, the `bindfs` package shows up under the 'Suggests' category, letting the process install the package actually allowed the service to run as expected and fixed the problem.

It seems that this package is actually *required* by `lightdm` to work, but is (incorrectly) not listed as such, so `lightdm` ends up in a broken state after upgrading.

To fix this, just re-install it to make sure dependencies are met.